# How to hide an object while it is in precollision event state in Corono SDK?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I need to hide object while it is in precollision event here is the code i tried.

```
-- Remove event listeners
function bird:preCollision(event)
    local platform = event.other
    if platform.myName == "object" then
        scoreText.text = scoreText.text + 1;
        obejct.isVisible = false;
    end
end
bird:addEventListener( "preCollision")
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `platform.isVisible` not `obejct.isVisible`.

Side note: you don't need semicolons and the comment is wrong.